# odata4j support for OData version 4.0

Tags: odata, odata4j

As per my knowledge of odata4j,odata4j is supporting OData v1-v3. Is odata4j going to support OData protocol version 4.0 ? Is there any community that is actively working on this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like that the odata4j library is not going to support OData v4.

You can try follow the [Apache Olingo project](http://olingo.apache.org/) instead if you would like to use a Java library that supports OData v4. It is clearly stated on the project homepage that although it currently only supports v2, OData v4 is in scope and people are proactively working on it. It is also an open source project and you can view the detailed working progress of it [here](https://incubator.apache.org/projects/olingo.html).

Comment: +1 here, I was using odata4j (V3, 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT) in my project and this initiative is unfortunately quite "dead". I will be switching to Apache Olingo as well.

Comment: same here.Will have to switch to Apache Olingo.